# How to include a code fragment inside .env as a variable?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, google-tag-manager

I have a React app and now I need to include the Google Tag Manager in my app. **I have two environments as dev and prod**. Google provides two different code fragments for the two environments, So as far as I know, these code fragments need to be included inside the .env file and need to be included inside the index.html with the syntax "`%REACT_APP_%`" So I tried as follows

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_HEAD=<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-KW2QJK3');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

When I do this, only the first line is taken as the code and I think that because the compiler doesn't identify multiple lines of declarations. So here are the two solutions I identified so far.

1. Put different variables for each line in the code fragment in the .env
2. Get the whole code as a single line inside the .env

**I need to know that, is there any other better method to get this done? Like is there any way to define a code fragment inside .env or declare multiple lines for a single variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module), it worked for me and is a clean way to do it.